# Parsing a JSON tree with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse [this](https://nopaste.xyz/?df38b93b1d0f6153#kKNf5TioVo/JZX0VFIxNufhkWbhGuwNi7i4lwYCO7Gc=) JSON tree on the basis of the 'Name' attribute and return the matched node/nodes as an array of objects.

Kindly paste the JSON tree in here - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
to get a better visualization of it.

The scenario would be such that, if the user enters 'Rule', all nodes that contain 'Rule*' corresponding to the 'Name' attribute would be returned.

To elaborate, the match would be such that `if (object.Name.includes('Rule'))`  it would be valid match.

Since the JSON tree is huge and has children embedded within children, I was using Defiant.js and the function was built like this -

```
$scope.doASearch = function(elm) {
        var as = '//*[contains(Name, ' + '"' + elm + '"' + ')]';
        $scope.found = JSON.search($scope.treedata, as);
        $scope.treedata = _.uniq($scope.found, 'MetaCatID');
};
```

Since DefiantJS does not work on Microsoft's Edge Browser, switching to a compalitibility mode like IE-10 makes DefiantJS work but is breaking few other things. So, I had to rule out DefiantJS.

Is another JSON parsing library available to help me out or a JavaScript or jQuery solution which can do it me ?

Comment: how about you post a "minimal" version of the JSON tree in the question itself, rather than a link that will go stale once you get your answer, no doubt

Comment: @JaromandaX - Kindly paste the JSON tree on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to get a better view of it.

Comment: what is the problem with `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @smnbbrv - `JSON.parse()` works but I find it difficult to crawl across each node and child node of the tree.

Comment: how should look like the result?

Comment: what is difficult in there? Just a recursive function with couple of if statements

Comment: @NinaScholz - An array of objects holding each matched node as in individual object.

Comment: @smnbbrv - How about just framming your suggestion in code ?

Comment: If there were clear requirements...

Comment: @smnbbrv - If the parent node matches the condition, I just need the parent node, if any of the nodes under 'subCategories' match the condition I would need that to. The children of 'subCategories' can also have 'subCategories', I need those too if they match the condition. This can go upto to 'n'.

Comment: `Kindly paste the JSON` - that's not the point ... the point is the question should be understandable in two weeks, two months, two years ... is that link going to be valid then?

Comment: That link is no longer valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by checking the types of the items and iterate accordingly.

This proposal uses a callback for checking the object and return the actual object if condition is met.

```js
function search(array, fn) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(o) {
        if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') {
            return;
        }
        if (fn(o)) {
            result.push(o);
            return;
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            iter(o[k]);
        });
    });
    return result;
}

var data = [{ tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 517, ParentMetaCatRef: 0, Name: "D Application" } } }, MetaCatID: 517, ParentMetaCatRef: 0, Name: "D Application", subCategories: [{ tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 518, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "Compass" } } }, MetaCatID: 518, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "Compass" }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 519, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "Orbe" } } }, MetaCatID: 519, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "Orbe" }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 520, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "PSI" } } }, MetaCatID: 520, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "PSI" }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 521, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "SAP" } } }, MetaCatID: 521, ParentMetaCatRef: 517, Name: "SAP" }] }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 541, ParentMetaCatRef: 0, Name: "D Versions" } } }, MetaCatID: 541, ParentMetaCatRef: 0, Name: "D Versions", subCategories: [{ tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 542, ParentMetaCatRef: 541, Name: "Baseline 2016-12-31" } } }, MetaCatID: 542, ParentMetaCatRef: 541, Name: "Baseline 2016-12-31" }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 543, ParentMetaCatRef: 541, Name: "CLS step 3 2017-04-15" } } }, MetaCatID: 543, ParentMetaCatRef: 541, Name: "CLS step 3 2017-04-15" }] }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 365, ParentMetaCatRef: 0, Name: "Market" } } }, MetaCatID: 365, ParentMetaCatRef: 0, Name: "Market", subCategories: [{ tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 366, ParentMetaCatRef: 365, Name: "Sector" } } }, MetaCatID: 366, ParentMetaCatRef: 365, Name: "Sector", subCategories: [{ tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 463, ParentMetaCatRef: 366, Name: "term" } } }, MetaCatID: 463, ParentMetaCatRef: 366, Name: "term" }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 464, ParentMetaCatRef: 366, Name: "category" } } }, MetaCatID: 464, ParentMetaCatRef: 366, Name: "category" }, { tuple: { old: { MetaCategory: { MetaCatID: 367, ParentMetaCatRef: 366, Name: "Subsector" } } }, MetaCatID: 367, ParentMetaCatRef: 366, Name: "Subsector" }] }] }];

console.log(search(data, function (o) { return o.MetaCatID > 500; }));
console.log(search(data, function (o) { return o.Name && o.Name.includes('P'); }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It is not working when I use String.contains or String.includes.
Have a look here - https://jsbin.com/cuwocupelo/edit?html,js,console

Comment: maybe your browser does not support the methods. where should i look at jsbin?

Comment: you need a check for the property first. i changed the function a bit.

Comment: The problem was due to the property going `undefined` in some cases so I fixed it like this - `if(o.Name !== undefined) return (o.Name.indexOf('PS') >= 0);`. Since Internet Explorer or Edge do not support the methods `String.contains` or `String.includes`, I had to use the `indexOf`